# cosmos query returns document in Azure Dev environment but not in Azure QA environment

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Below is the query which gets executed on Azure Dev environment and also returns the document

`{ "$or" : [ { "$and" : [ { "restrictions" : { "$elemMatch" : { "city" : { "$regex" : "Austin" , "$options" : "i"} , "state" : { "$regex" : "Texas" , "$options" : "i"} , "postalCode" :  null  , "location" :  null }}}]} , { "itemNumber" : { "$in" : [ ]}} , { "gtin" : { "$in" : [ ]}}]}`

Same query if I execute on Azure QA environment then result will be nothing (Fetched document 0).

There is a same image in both the environment.

Comment: This is very little to work with. Are you running this query mongoDB? Is your local and QA environments using the same DB (same as in the same instance, not same data)? Are you sure the data is the same?

Comment: Two different application instances with two seperate databases(COSMOSDB with MongoDb Api) and same data(documents) in two database instances. When we run Query in DEV environment, we are getting responses as expected,but not in QA..

Comment: Did you configure everything correctly in your QA environment?

Comment: yeah everything has done perfect